# Gradient Blowup for a Parabolic (Heat) Equation

Tags: boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, singularity, parabolic-pde

Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution to the following parabolic PDE:

With $\alpha \in (0,1)$,
\begin{align}
\partial_t u(x,t) &= \alpha (1-t)^{\alpha - 1} \partial_x u(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} u(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in (-\infty,1] \times [0,1] \\
u(x,0) &= f(x),\\
u(1,t) &= u(-\infty,t) = 0 \quad \text{(boundary condition)}
\end{align}
Here $f \in C^2$, $\; f \geq 0$,  $\; \int f^2(x)dx < \infty$, $\; f(1) = f(-\infty) = 0$.

I'm especially interested in the case $\alpha < 1/2$, but $\alpha \in [1/2,1)$ is also valuable.

**Note that** the coefficient of $\partial_x u$, i.e  $\alpha (1-t)^{\alpha -1}$ becomes unbounded at $t = 1$.

**I'm trying to show that** $$-\partial_xu(x,t)|_{x=1} \geq \kappa (1-t)^{\alpha-1} \quad \text{ as } \quad  t \to 1, \quad (\kappa > 0 \text{ constant})$$ i.e. the right side boundary $(x = 1)$ gradient blows up at the rate at least $(1 - t)^{\alpha - 1}$ as $t \to 1$.

**We can try** the transformation $(z,r) = (\mu x, \mu^2 t)$ for some $\mu > 0$, and define $\xi(x,t) = u(z,r)$ for $(x,t) \in (-\infty, 1/\mu] \times [0,1/\mu^2].$ Then we see that 
\begin{align}
\xi_x(x,t) &= \mu u_z(z,r), \\
\xi_{xx}(x,t) &= \mu^2 u_{zz}(z,r), \\
\xi_t(x,t) &= \mu^2 u_r(z,r),
\end{align}
so that $\xi$ solves the Dirichlet problem

\begin{align}
\partial_t \xi(x,t) &= \alpha \mu (1-\mu^2 t)^{\alpha - 1} \partial_x \xi(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} \xi(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in (-\infty,1/\mu] \times [0,1/\mu^2] \\
\xi(x,0) &= f(\mu x),\\
\xi(1/\mu,t) &= \xi(-\infty,t) = 0 \quad \text{for }t \in[0,1/\mu^2]
\end{align}
Next, for each fixed $T < 1$, we restrict the solution of the above problem to $t \in [0,T/\mu^2]$ and set the scaling 
$$\mu = \mu_T = (1 - \mu^2 t)^{1 - \alpha}|_{t = T/\mu^2} = (1 - T)^{1 - \alpha}.$$
This means that on each strip $(x,t) \in (-\infty,1/\mu_T)\times [0,T/\mu_T^2]$ and with the scaling $\mu = \mu_T$, the coefficients of the equation are (uniformly) bounded, and it has a solution in the classical sense.

Also, for each $T$, by Hopf's boundary gradient lemma, $\partial_x \xi(x, T/\mu_T^2 )|_{x = 1/\mu_T} = C_T > 0$ (boundary gradient is strictly positive).

This means that 
$$\partial_x u(1,T) = C_T / \mu_T = C_T(1-T)^{\alpha - 1}$$.

This would be complete the proof, but unfortunately, as $T \to 1$, the right lateral boundary $x = 1/\mu_T$ becomes unbounded and Hopf lemma fails. In other words, the asymptoic factor $C_T$ is not uniformly boubded from below. In fact, I suspect $C_T \to 0$ as $T \to 1$, and the argument is not enough to complete the proof. I need to show that $C_T > C > 0, \forall T$ (probably not true), or revise the estimate by showing that $C_T \searrow 0$ slowly (logarithmic etc), or use a completely different tactic.

NB. I already have an asymptotic upper bound on $-\partial_x u(x,t)|_{x = 1}$:
$$-\partial_x u(x,t)|_{x = 1} \leq (1 - t)^{1 - \alpha} \text{ as } t \to 1,$$ $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

**Any ideas?** I'll start a bounty when I'm allowed.

Comment: Some nitpicking: the case $f\equiv0$ excluded, the Zaremba-Giraud (or Hopf who was later) lemma gives in this case $\partial_xu(x,t)|_{x=1}<0$ so, if the estimate is required without absolute value, it's trivially true.

Comment: @Andrew - yes absolutely true on both counts. Boundary gradient is negative, and I am infact looking for an asymptotic lower bound for $−\partial_x u(t,x)|_{x=1}$ as $t \to 1$. Any suggestions? A different scaling perhaps? Or a sub-parabolic function (sub-temperature) whose gradient($\times -1$) blows up at the same rate while staying below u?

Comment: Was the equation obtained by a change of variables to straighten the boundary? Btw returning to the heat eqn and curved boundary gets that there will be no growth at least for $\alpha>1/2$.

Comment: Yes exactly - the original problem was the standard heat equation in the domain $(t,x):t∈[0,1], x \leq (1−t)^\alpha$. I'm trying to find the rate of gradient blowup at the right boundary $(x=(1−t)^\alpha)$ as $t \to 1$. The solution itself remains bounded by the $\int f(x) e^{-x^2/(2t)}/\sqrt{2\pi t}dx$ (obviously) but my intuition is that the gradient at the boundary should go like $(1−t)^{\alpha−1}$ as $t \to \infty$ as soon as $\alpha <1/2$. It is not immediately obvious to me that "there will be no growth for $\alpha>1/2$. Can you direct me to a proof? I don't know the pde literature well.

Comment: In the original problem the boundary belongs to the Holder class $C^{2\alpha}$ (exponent counted with factor 2 because of anisotropy). For $2\alpha=1+\beta$ when $0<\beta<1$ ($\alpha>1/2$) the solution belongs to the parabolic Holder class $C^{1+\beta}(\bar \Omega)$ in the closure of the domain in question $\Omega$. it means $\partial_xu\in C^{\beta}$, and so continuous and bounded up in $\bar \Omega$. For n-dimensional case see  Baderko, E. A., ‘Boundary value problems for a parabolic equation, and boundary integral equations’,
Diff. Eq., 28, 15—20 (1992), there are ref. for the case $n=1$.

Comment: I have some reasons to believe the growth is as $(1-t)^{\alpha-1/2}$ for $0<\alpha<1/2$ and $\log(1-t) $ for $\alpha=1/2$, but not a complete proof. This agrees with the scale of the previous comment, $\partial_xu\in C^{\beta}$, $\beta=2\alpha-1$ being now non-positive. And the exponent wrt $t$ will should be divided by 2.